# possible cause for the water heater being unable to be lighted

Tags: water-heater

The water heater could not be lighted. I tried several times without being successful. What could be the possible causes for the water heater to fail to be lighted. This water heater is only 1 and half years old.

Comment: Make and model would be helpful here as well a description of what you tried to do light it, any error codes, etc. Without this basic information, any answers will be very generalized.

Comment: Also, what caused it to go out in the first place? Did you shut it off? Did it go out on its own? Did the gas company shut off your supply temporarily for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are one user failure and 2 equipment fails that usually contribute to non lighting water heaters"

**User**

Not pressing down the pilot button long enough.  After lighting the pilot flame initially, you must hold down the pilot button long enough (30 seconds) to allow the thermocouple (a detector of heat, which sents its signal to the main gas valve) to heat up enough.

**Equipment**

1. Thermocouple is broken ***or*** misadjusted so that the pilot flame dosen't heat it.
2. Main gas valve broken.  This must be replaced as there are no 'user serviceable parts' inside.